# Check an element is present if another one is not

Tags: eclipse, selenium, if-statement, robotframework

I wanted to know how I can use keyword "run keyword if" for my script.
For Context, my webpage has a graph that shows if users have been connected and if no users are connected it shows a "No data Found" image.
So, i want to use "run keyword if" with "Page should contain Element     *Locator*" for the graph.
if it passes , well and good, if not, I want to use "ELSE Page should contain element  *Locator*" for the no data found image.
So, how do I go on about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining it with `Run Keyword And Return Status` - your want to first check for one of the conditions, the most probable - say it's the graph being present; and if it's not, then check for the other case:

```
${graph shown}=    Run Keyword And Return Status     Page should contain Element    Locator_graph
Run Keyword If     not ${graph shown}   Page should contain Element    Locator_no_data
```

BTW if you're using Robot Framework v5 and up, you can use `IF` instead of `Run Keyword If`

Comment: It works. Thanks. @Todor Minakov. Also is there any way to use multiple keywords after page should contain element     *Locator* ? For example, i want to use log after each page should contain element. So is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use an `IF ... END` block and add any calls you need inside it, when the condition is met. Mind you, this is a RF v5 feature, in not sure what version you're using.